# Loading .rtf file from resources into RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, embedded-resource, rtf

I've seen some topics on this subject but none of them wants to work in my case. In my Windows Forms app I have a ordinary `Resources`catalog containing some images and `.rtf` files. It looks like this:

[image]

There's no problem for me to load pictures from it as:

```
Bitmap bmp = Properties.Resources.Cut_6523;
```

But, for some reason, I am unable to do the same with `.rtf` files (only bitmaps are available).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you store a `.rft` file as resource using resource designer, the resource designer creates a `string` property for it that returns rich text.

So you can set the content of `RichTextBox` to rich text using [`SelectedRtf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedrtf(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
this.richTextBox1.SelectAll();
this.richTextBox1.SelectedRtf = Properties.Resources.YourRTFResourceName;
```

Also as another option, you can cache that resource as a file in your application directory at run-time and then use [`richTextBox1.LoadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7(v=vs.110).aspx) to load rich text.

Comment: When I store a `.rtf` file as resource, it is added to `Files` category. It's true that later using `Properties.Resources.MyRTFResourceName` returns `string` with `RTF` formatting, but there's no possibility for me to change it's `Persistence` property to `Embdeeded with .resx`. Can I do anything about it?

Comment: Thanks I used this and it helped me out

Answer (score 0):

i don't sure it's will work for C#, i code this for .Net try to convert this code.

```
RichTextBox1.LoadFile(Application.StartupPath & "\user_guide.rtf")
```

well that's my code on "VB.NET"

Comment: Thanks, but I want to put a file into resources so that it would be embdeeded.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the folder where your files are laying on your disk. Somewhere in your project, there is also a `.resx` file (probably under *Properties*). Open that file by a double-click and drag-drop your .rtf file from the solution explorer over the designer view of the `.resx`file.

Comment: Hi. That almost solves my problem. I mean, I can refference the files from `Resources`, but I can't change `Persistence` property for them to be `Embdeeded with .resx` as I might to with Images. Have you any idea why it is like that?